Targeting Android API 34 in .NET MAUI app
I have a .NET MAUI app built on .NET 8, using the latest updates, etc.
I received an email from Google Play stating that my app needs to target Android API 34 due to their current support policies.
I right clicked my project and selected Properties and set the targets under Application > Android Targets -- see image below.

I then got an error stating that the targets in AndroidManifest.xml did not match the project file. So I updated it to the following:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="32" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
Now, when I try to build my project, I get the following error but I had already deleted both bin and obj folders so they don't even exist right now. Here's the error:

Assets file 'my-project-folder\my-project\obj\project.assets.json'
doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android34.0' Ensure that restore has
run and that you have included 'net8.0-android34.0' in the
TargetFrameworks for your project.

I have run dotnet restore several times. The first time I did, it updated the workload to 8.0.7. I had updated Visual Studio to the latest version earlier today so I assume the workload was not updated properly.
And this is what I'm seeing in the project file:
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android34.0</TargetFrameworks>
Any suggestions about how to fix this issue? Currently, I can't compile my project.
Update:
Here's what I got when I ran dotnet workload list:

I then ran dotnet workload update but still getting the same error when I try to build my project.

In your Command Prompt, input dotnet workload list, what is the Workload versions for Android?

See the update section in original message. There were some updates so I ran dotnet workload update but still getting the same error.

Thanks for the update. Please don't set Target Android Framework to Android 14.0(API Level 34) under  Application > Android Targets and in CSPOJ file change it to <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks> . And set the targets only in AndroidManifest.xml like <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="32" android:targetSdkVersion="34" /> in

Thank you! Not setting the target framework in properties/project file seems to fix the issue but does that mean I'm not addressing Google Play Store's requirement about not targeting Android API 34? I never had the Android API specified in properties/project file before. The only reason why I did that was to address the email I got from Google Play.

I guess the entry in AndroidManifest.xml addresses the Google Play requirement. Am I correct in that assumption?

Nice catch!! :)

@AlexandarMay-MSFT Can you explain why not to set Target Android Framework to Android 14.0? This seems counter intuitive. Thanks

Note that if you're using net8.0, the default Target Android Framework as you set under Application > Android Targets is Android 14.0(API Level 34) (see here). So you don't need to set it. This setting is used to set the compiling API for the project.
To fix your issue, you can use the <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="32" android:targetSdkVersion="34" in AndroidManifest.xml to meet the Google Play requirement. See Why target newer SDKs?.

Thank you! Really appreciate your help and all the info you provided!

Can you explain why not to set Target Android Framework to Android 14.0? This seems counter intuitive. Thanks

@ledragon As I posted in my answer, this is used to set the compiling API for the project, the default Target Android Framework is Android 14.0(API Level 34) if you're using .net8. Therefore there's no need to set it in VS.

OK thanks...so there is no need rather than don't do it? I was a little unclear due to your comment on the original post "Please don't set Target Android Framework to Android 14.0(API Level 34)".

@ledragon I would suggest that you don't do it. My MAUI app fails to build if I set it in the csproj.

I'd really like some more clarity @AlexandarMay-MSFT around when to use the specific "Android Targets" option vs the uses-sdk element in the Manifest file

It is recommended to delete <uses-sdk /> from AndroidManifest.xml and use MSBuild properties like SupportedOSPlatformVersion.

In .NET 8 Android apps, there are MSBuild properties to set these
values. Using the MSBuild properties has other benefits. In most cases
the  element should be removed in favor of values in your
project's .csproj file

More on this topic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/android-projects?view=net-maui-9.0
